# How to add Barcode in invoice pdf in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I want to print "Barcode"(image) in invoice means when we generate invoice from admin panel the that invoice should contain  all product related details along with barcode image .I saw all questions related to above problem but i did't satisfy.

Please tell me step by step instruction where we have to modify files (file path) for adding barcode attribute to pdf.

Comment: This is similar to your, plez [check](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/2922/adding-a-barcode-for-order-number-and-tracking-number-in-shipment-pdf).

Comment: i saw this but i didn't understand where (file path)this  'Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Packaging ' i will get.How can i modify that file?

Comment: Is any one have solution for this??

Comment: `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Packaging` is in `app/code/core/mage/sales/model/order/pdf/packaging`.

Comment: i added that code there but it was not working.any other solution you have.....when we generate invoice from admin panel then porducts detail only display in that pdf file ..

Comment: Check these extensions: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalogsearch/result/?q=barcode+in+invoice&pl=0

Comment: ok i will try and let you know

Answer (score 1):

We implemented a barcode on the PDF in [FireGento_Pdf](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf/). In this case, the barcode represents the order number. But you could have a look at the code to see how it is done [here](https://github.com/firegento/firegento-pdf/commit/d0d708528064e249aef7ec92c4c0f5a8d55abb4f#diff-dfe7480ccebbd0a926c403d441e140e3). The main part is this:

```
$barcodeConfig = array(
    'drawText' => false,
    'orientation' => 90,
    'text' => $order->getIncrementId()
);
$rendererConfig = array(
    'verticalPosition' => 'middle',
    'moduleSize' => 0.9
);
// create dummy Zend_Pdf object, which just stores the current page, so that we can pass it in
// Zend_Barcode_Renderer_Pdf->setResource()
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
$pdf->pages[] = $page;
/** @var $renderer Zend_Barcode_Renderer_Pdf */
$renderer = Zend_Barcode::factory('code128', 'pdf', $barcodeConfig, $rendererConfig)->setResource($pdf, 0);
// calculate left offset so that barcode is printed on the right with a little margin
$leftOffset = $page->getWidth() - $renderer->getBarcode()->getWidth(true) * $renderer->getModuleSize() - 10;
$renderer->setLeftOffset($leftOffset);
$renderer->draw();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created POS scanning barcode in magento invoice. It's very simple and easy to customize for single product or invoice number.

**Edit :** app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php

```
$fontPath = 'fonts/code39.TTF';                                
$barcodeImage = "*".$pro_sku."*";
$page->setFont(Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath($fontPath), 36);

//Draw image to PDF
$page->drawText($barcodeImage, 400, 800);
```

POS easy to scan code39 fonts.

Comment: The core should not be edited. The class should be overridden via a custom module.