# Sort order field in PayUMoney checkout payment method is not showing in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, admin-panel

I integrate PayUMoney checkout payment method into my website successfully.Two  payment option is available on frontend :

1.Payu Checkout 
2.Check / Money order

but I want to change display order of payment methods i.e

1.Check / Money order 
2.Payu Checkout

[image]

In admin panel i fill all fields
[image]

but "sort order" field is not showing in setting.see image
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like your `system.xml` may be missing this node in your extension

```
 <sort_order translate="label">
       <label>Sort Order</label>
       <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
       <sort_order>100</sort_order>
       <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
       <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
       <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
       <frontend_class>validate-number</frontend_class>
</sort_order>
```

hope this will be worth for you.

Comment: can you help me in this also http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71188/how-to-add-barcode-in-invoice-pdf-in-magento