# Barcode in invoice magento

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice

How to create **Barcode** in **invoice** can any one suggest barcode in invoice

Comment: duplicate questions : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71188/how-to-add-barcode-in-invoice-pdf-in-magento

Answer (score 2):

You need to install image library for this. and add following code in your invoice.php

Override the invoice.php

```
app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php



/* Start Barcode */
                $dir_invoicebarcode = "invoicebarcode";
                $barCodeNo = $invoice->getIncrementId(); //For Order Number add this: $order->getIncrementId()

                header('Content-Type: image/png');
                $barcodeOptions = array('text' => $barCodeNo, 'barHeight'=> 30, 'factor'=>1,);
                $rendererOptions = array();
                $imageResource = Zend_Barcode::draw(
                 'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
                );
                $upload_path = str_replace("\\/","/",Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.$dir_invoicebarcode.DS.$barCodeNo."_barcode.png");
                chmod($upload_path,0777);
                imagepng($imageResource,$upload_path, 0, NULL);
                imagedestroy($imageResource);

                $barcode_image = $upload_path;
                $barcode_y = $page->getHeight()- 30 ;
                if (is_file($barcode_image)) {
                 $barcode_image = Zend_Pdf_Image::imageWithPath($barcode_image);
                    $page->drawImage($barcode_image, 240, $barcode_y - 30, 350, $barcode_y);
                }
                /* End Barcode*/
```

Comment: under which method i need to add i didn't see any barcode after adding this in my pdf

Comment: Hi you need to add this in public function getPdf($invoices = array()) methis

Comment: Please create folder under the media folder like this app/media/invoicebarcode. after that please comment the header('Content-Type: image/png'); line from the above code. and set relative positive  here drawImage($barcode_image, 240, $barcode_y - 30, 350, $barcode_y);  based on your PDF

Comment: No i am not getting same only

Comment: sorry?? i cant understand

Comment: whats problem please tell me?

Comment: Image is not printing in invoice

Comment: can you set proper co-ordinates for image?

Comment: Soory i am new from this can you please explain it

Comment: you need to set manually last 4 coordinates according to your PDF.

Comment: $page->drawImage($barcode_image, 240, $barcode_y - 30, 350, $barcode_y);

Comment: add me skype : maitri.infosys