# Check producs barcode before shipping product

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, extensions, shipping

We use magento 1.8.1ce

All items already have an attribute (barcode). We use this with a POS extension. And that works great.

I am looking for a solution where the product's barcode should be scanned before shipping the product. This to verify the right product is being shipped.

Order handeling

1. An order is placed
2. The order is being picked based on the sku/picture of the product
3. **Our wish: The packing begins. The barcode of the item must first be
       scanned to verify its the right item. When its the wrong item the
       orderpicker must be notified**
4. The order is shipped

We want an extra validation that the right item is being shipped, so the chance a client receives a wrong items is being norrowed down.

Is there an extension what can do this?

Comment: try this http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/2964/14174